# Export PHP table in a HTML file

Tags: php, html, save, export

I need your help.
I have a php page that through a series of queries populates a table.

I function, which through a click of a button I export the table to Excel.
I need to export this table in an html file always clicking on a button.

How could I do?

Comment: How are you already exporting to Excel? If you're doing that, then you're already doing ¾ or the work that you need to export it to html

Comment: Yes, the export in Excel works very well. How I do for an export in html?

Comment: So how are you doing the export to Excel? Knowing that information allows us to better answer your question

Comment: I added the code used to export in excel in the answers:)

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but that javascript code doesn't create an Excel file. It just wraps the html in some xml, and relies on the fact that MS Excel has an importer for html.... you could use exactly the same code with the xml tags stripped out to give you vanilla html

Comment: If I remove xml tags, the file is downloaded and open direclty with excel...

Comment: Change `data:application/vnd.ms-excel` to `data:text/html`.... that's the bit that tells the browser whether to treat is as an excel file, or as html to be rendered in the browser itself

Comment: Great! Works :D 
Thanks

A last request: There is a automatic mode for saving the html export?

Comment: You should really tag this for asking js folks, your code is purely js, nothing to do with server-side code like PHP at all

Comment: Ok, thanks you for all :)

Answer (score 0):

It is 3 a easy step process:

1 - The first thing you have to do is add an application/vnd.ms-excel content-type to your PHP file:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

2 - Data is just as simple. Separate cells/columns with tabs (“\t” in PHP) and move to the next row with a newline (“\n” in PHP).

```
echo 'First Name' . "\t" . 'Last Name' . "\t" . 'Phone' . "\n";
echo 'John' . "\t" . 'Doe' . "\t" . '555-5555' . "\n";
```

separated the tabs (\t) and the new lines (\n) so you can easily see the structure. The above would create a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
First Name     Last Name     Phone
John           Doe           555-5555
```

Step 3: Downloading the Spreadsheet

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls");
```

Download the example files from [here](http://www.lateralcode.com/excel-spreadsheets-php/).

You can also use [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home) to generate excel files.

Comment: Note that you're creating a CSV file, not an Excel file; you're ignoring PHP's built-in fputcsv() function which would correctly handle fields containing tabs and quotes (whereas your "homebrew" will break); and the OP says that they can already create an Excel file, and want to create HTML

Answer (score 0):

I use this Java script function

```
[link]<script type="text/javascript">
        var tableToExcel = (function() 
        {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function(table, name)
        {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
        })()
</script>
```